# Как задать имя каждому наблюдению в объекте типа data.frame

Tags: r, data.frame

Давно крутился в голове вопрос, пока не возникла необходимость.
Имеются следующие данные:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Рисую `biplot` :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно чтобы вместо номера наблюдения, он писал название города. Во всех встроенных данных эти названия уже есть и такой проблемы не возникает. Можно ли указать, что city не просто одна из переменных, но именно идентификатор (имя) каждого наблюдения  ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, не вставляйте скриншоты данных в вопросы. Используйте функцию `dput()` для формирование образца данных. Пример: `dput(head(mtcars))`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нужно задать имена строк `rownames`:

```
rownames(data) <- data$city
```

Answer (score 2):

При загрузке данных с помощью `read.table`, `read.csv` или `read.delim` можно указать аргумент `row.names=1`, т.е. использовать первый столбец в качестве имён строк, например:

```
cities<-read.delim("~/города.txt", row.names=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Не обязательно использовать умолчания `biplot.procmp()`. Можно явно передать параметр более общей функции `biplot()` используя параметр `xlabs=вектор_имен`.

В описываемом случае:

```
biplot(prcomp(pca[,-1]), xlabs=pca[,1])
```